# Jquery Mobile HTML element selection issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

While working with jquery mobile, got a weird issue with content grids.

There was a hidden-variable & an image within a content-grid, which I wanted to manipulate.

My code was-

```
$('#ratings').val($rate);
$('#ratingStar_'+$i).attr('src', 'images/star_icon.png');
```

this snippet worked locally; but **not** in the server.

Then modifying it to the following, made it work-

```
$('.ui-grid-a .ui-block-b #ratings').val($rate);
$('.ui-grid-a .ui-block-b #ratingStar_'+$i).attr('src', 'images/star_icon.png');
```

the id of elements are absolutely UNIQUE & was using jquery mobile beta 1.0.

What can be the issue ?

Comment: Would need a little more code, maybe a link to a demo site? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the exact context I can't tell for sure. But in general, when you use frameworks such as jQuery Mobile, you should avoid selecting HTML elements in the DOM tree by using their `id` attribute value.

As it is explained [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/ui#javascript-frameworks) by the Rhomobile team  (in the "Important notes!" section), it has something to do with the way such kind of frameworks performs page caching.

The reliable way to select some exact element with jQuery (when using frameworks such as jQuery Mobile) is:

```
// this code will return exact span element from the current active page
var ratingsElement = $("div.ui-page-active span.ratings");
```